# How to spoof accounts using Foundry?

Tags: solidity, testing, test, foundry

Currently using Foundry & Hardhat for development, Foundry for testing & Hardhat for deployment. I'm trying to fuzz a test input of a function that adds an address to a whitelist and I need a way of dynamically generating accounts to be tested (added to the whitelist).

When looking at the Foundry docs I was under the impression that it would automatically fuzz any test function args, however I've now realized that that works for other primitives, but not addresses. Essentially what I'm asking is if there is any way to replicate the ethers code `const [address, address1, address2, ...addrs] = ethers.getSigners()` in Foundry (ie in Solidity instead of JS)?

If not, what are some viable workarounds?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Since the address number doesn't matter, I'd prefer hardcoded number like `address addr1 = address(0x1234)`, easier for debugging.

Answer (score 7):

There is even a simpler solution than suggested by adijo.

```
address someUser = vm.addr(somePrivateKey);
```

To get the private key either use an integer > 0, or do it more properly like this

```
string memory mnemonic = "test test test test test test test test test test test junk";
uint256 privateKey = vm.deriveKey(mnemonic, 0);
```

call the next function on behalf of this newly created user with vm.prank

```
vm.prank(someUser);
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do this using [Cheatcodes](https://onbjerg.github.io/foundry-book/forge/cheatcodes.html) using the [`addr` function:](https://github.com/gakonst/foundry/blob/master/testdata/cheats/Cheats.sol#L17)

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

import "ds-test/test.sol";

interface CheatCodes {
   // Gets address for a given private key, (privateKey) => (address)
   function addr(uint256) external returns (address);
}

contract Test is DSTest {
    address public owner;
    address public addr1;
    address public addr2;
 
    CheatCodes cheats = CheatCodes(HEVM_ADDRESS);
     
    function setUp() {

        // new deployed contracts will have Test as owner
        owner = address(this); 
       
        addr1 = cheats.addr(1);
        addr2 = cheats.addr(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: also works with `import "forge-std/Test.sol";` instead of `import "ds-test/test.sol";` for those that are curious or confused

Answer (score 2):

Sure, here's an example. First, run `forge init`, this will instantiate a new foundry project with the latest project structure using [`forge-std`](https://github.com/foundry-rs/forge-std/), Foundry's standard library which contains a bunch of helper functions.

Then, you can do something like this, adapted from [@FrankieIsLost's Github](https://github.com/FrankieIsLost/forge-template/blob/master/src/test/utils/Utilities.sol).

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";

contract TestWithAccounts is Test {
    // Create users with 100 ether balance
    function createUsers(uint256 userNum)
        external
        returns (address[] memory)
    {
        address[] memory users = new address[](userNum);

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < userNum; i++) {
            // This will create a new address using `keccak256(i)` as the private key
            address user = vm.addr(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(i)));
            vm.deal(user, 100 ether);
            users[i] = user;
        }

        return users;
    }

    function testManyUsers() external {
        address[] memory users = createUsers(3);
        vm.prank(users[0]);
        // do something as users[0];
    }
}
```

If you want to re-use these users in your tests, you can modify `createUsers` (or in your constructor/setUp function) to instead push to an array that's a state variable of the contract, instead of returning it in memory.

Comment: for `address user = vm.addr(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(i)));`

Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from bytes32 to uint256 requested.(9553)

and for  `address[] memory users = createUsers(3);`

Undeclared identifier. "createUsers" is not (or not yet) visible at this point.(7576)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create addresses with `makeAddr` and `vm.addr`

```
address alice = makeAddr("alice");
address bob = makeAddr("bob");
```

If you need to generate a sequence of them, you can still use `makeAddr` or `vm.addr`

```
for (uint8 i = 0; i < someLimit; i++) {
  address account1 = makeAddr(vm.toString(i));
  // or
  address account2 = vm.addr(i + 1);
}
```

And use them like you would with any address with `vm.prank` or `hoax`

Answer (score 0):

There are commonly 2 ways to spoofing addresses in Foundry tests:

1. Simple address creation:

`address public user;`

2. Using private key and `makeAddr`

`address public user=makeAddr("Any Random String as Private Key");`